# Loading whisper base model from hugging face?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, openai-api

I am trying to load the base model of whisper, but I am having difficulty doing so.
There doesn't seem to be a direct way to download the model directly from the hugging face website, and using transformers doesn't work. I know I'm doing something wrong, as i all I know I'm loading the model 2 times, and I can't do that.

Currently, this is what I've tried:

```
import whisper
import torch
from transformers import AutoProcessor, AutoModelForSpeechSeq2Seq
print("Downloading the model...")
direct = "model/"
model_1 = AutoModelForSpeechSeq2Seq.from_pretrained('openai/whisper-base', cache_dir=direct)
processor = AutoProcessor.from_pretrained('openai/whisper-base', cache_dir=direct)

model = whisper.load_model(model_1)
print("Model loaded. Transcribing test audio...")
result = model.transcribe("audio_test.mp3")
print(result["text"])
```

Do I need to use transformers? Is there another way I should be doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [model documentation](https://huggingface.co/openai/whisper-base) code?

```py
from transformers import WhisperProcessor, WhisperForConditionalGeneration
from datasets import load_dataset

# load model and processor
processor = WhisperProcessor.from_pretrained("openai/whisper-base")
model = WhisperForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained("openai/whisper-base")
model.config.forced_decoder_ids = None

# load dummy dataset and read audio files
ds = load_dataset("hf-internal-testing/librispeech_asr_dummy", "clean", split="validation")
sample = ds[0]["audio"]
input_features = processor(sample["array"], sampling_rate=sample["sampling_rate"], return_tensors="pt").input_features 

# generate token ids
predicted_ids = model.generate(input_features)
# decode token ids to text
transcription = processor.batch_decode(predicted_ids, skip_special_tokens=False)
>['<|startoftranscript|><|en|><|transcribe|><|notimestamps|> Mr. Quilter is the apostle of the middle classes and we are glad to welcome his gospel.<|endoftext|>']

transcription = processor.batch_decode(predicted_ids, skip_special_tokens=True)
>[' Mr. Quilter is the apostle of the middle classes and we are glad to welcome his gospel.']
```